# How can I show a quote from database in a cycle order?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to show only one quote from my database table by cyclic order when the page refresh or reload. I don't want to do it randomly. cycle like: 1,2,3....10 then back to 1. I need to do that using php or jquery. Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['quote_num']) || !is_numeric($_SESSION['quote_num']) || $_SESSION['quote_num'] >= 10) {
   $_SESSION['quote_num'] = 1;
} else {
   $_SESSION['quote_num'] += 1;
}


// Now execute your query. Make sure to do proper escaping of your query.
// SELECT .... WHERE quote_num = $_SESSION['quote_num']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you solved my problem. I need it to use for codeigniter where qoute was specific for every user by user id in a table. Following your logic I solved it.

Comment: Great, make sure to chose and answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

store this views number in session like so:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views'] = 1; // store session data
echo "Pageviews = ". $_SESSION['views']; //retrieve data
?>
```

from http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: you're welcome! can you upvote all useful replies and accept one, please? that's if you want people to help you in future.

Comment: anyway you need more rep to upvote. But you can select one answer as the accepted answer [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie with the current index, and every visit just increment it by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['c'])
{
    $_SESSION['c'] = 0;
}

if ($_SESSION['c'] == 10)
{
     $_SESSION['c'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['c']++;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cycle WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['c']);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['id'];
```